# How to tell google that I have another page instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

I have a aspx page : 1.aspx

I Dont have any routes in my app nor rewriteurl module.

How do I tell google :

I dont use 1.aspx anymore

Please use 2.aspx `instead`

his robots always searching for 1.aspx

How do i stop it ( and tell him to look for 2.aspx instead ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using a `robots.txt` file:**

You can create a `robots.txt` file at the root of your application and put the following in it:

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: 1.aspx
```

More on robots.txt files http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

---

**Doing a redirect:**

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location", "/2.aspx");
```

---

**Doing a redirect without that page existing in `Global.asax`:**

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string url = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    if (url.Contains("/1.aspx")) {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "/2.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i tell him 2.aspx instead ?

Comment: Robots is a directive, not a command.  The best way to let Google know that page does not exist is to 301 redirect the page.

Comment: @Chase so i will have to keep the 1.aspx ( and write the code in it ?) i dont want to keeo 1.aspx.......

Comment: If you want to delete the page you can do a server side redirect.  There are some suggestions here but they appear to be client side.  A server side 301 will allow you to remove the page completely.

Comment: @hunter  so i will have to keep the 1.aspx ( and write the code in it ?) i dont want to keeo 1.aspx.......

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes.  Unless you do a server side redirect... IIS, Apache, Godaddy, or whatever is hosting your application.

Comment: @hunter Don't you have to set `Response.StatusCode = 301;` as well?  I'd think that would be the most important part since it is probably the primary part of the response read by the webcrawler.

Answer (score 2):

Google will refresh that automatically. Remove the 1.aspx page from your website. The robot will then look for that file a while but will scan the rest and updates the index.

Comment: but my page was so well indexed and randked that i dont want him to do that again ... help ?

Comment: Then keep 1.aspx and put the new content in it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: As far as I understand your question and comments: You want to keep the address (= filename), but you don't need the file any longer, so there are the two options I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 301 Permanent Redirect. If you are using .NET < 4.0:

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
Response.End();
```

If you are using .NET 4.0:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.new-url.com");
```

You can learn move about a 301 redirect and how Google handles them [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633).

Comment: I dont want to keep 1.aspx ...? is that mean i have to ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir If URL rewriting is out of the picture, then yes. *Something* has to tell the search engine that the location of the page moved. In your case, 1.aspx would just do this redirect to 2.aspx.

Comment: @vcjones , If I delete 1.aspx  , will google try to search it forever ? or there is some time or X limitation ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir This is getting a little off topic. You may want to ask specific SEO questions on webmasters.stackexchange.com. But to answer it, I *beleive* Google will stop searching for it after it gets a few 404's. The downside to that is your page loses its rank if Google doesn't know where it moved to.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a 301 Redirect.

this will vary depending on your technology, however you can find out more at http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

**For example in ASP**

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.new-url.com/"
%>
```

**For ASP.NET**

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
}
</script>
```

You can read more on server side redirects here:

- http://www.mcanerin.com/en/articles/301-redirect-iis.asp
- http://www.mcanerin.com/en/articles/301-redirect-apache.asp

For Microsoft Internet Information Services and Apache respectively.

Comment: :) cheers! yeah the conversion to C# should be pretty straight forward!

Comment: so i will have to keep the 1.aspx ( and write the code in it ?) i dont want to keep 1.aspx......

Comment: if you don't want to keep the code around, understandable, you can use htaccess redirects or apache redirects (which is briefly explained on the link).  if you have that level of access of course, basically you just need to catch incomming requests on the server from that page and send them to the new page.

Comment: what server technology are you working with?  IIS or Apache or other?  This will greatly affect how you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirect 1.aspx to 2.aspx.

A client side redirect will force you to keep the page.  Server side redirect via IIS (or whatever is hosting your app) will permanently make 1.aspx -> 2.aspx.  You can delete the page and it won't matter.

Comment: You'll have to do this in IIS or whatever is hosting your application.  If you have a network admin he can do this for you.  If the content of a page has remained the same but the address has changed a 301 redirect is the best bet.